# BASH: Is it safe to have multiple bash background processes write to the same file?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that starts up multiple background scripts which all write to the same file. My script looks like this:

```
for (( COUNTER=0; ...)); do

    ./otherscript a b &

done
wait
```

and ./otherscript looks like this:

```
echo $1 $2 >> file.txt
```

Is this safe to do? There could potentially be 100s of these scripts run in the background and these will be running on Debian and Ubuntu systems.

Comment: At best, the order of the lines is unpredictable. At worst, a line from one file could appear in the middle of a line from another.

Comment: `echo $1 $2` is always buggy. Use `echo "$1 $2"` instead.

Comment: Oh -- also, which filesystem?  `O_APPEND` works right for most Linux filesystems (XFS,  ext4, etc), but emphatically *not* for NFS, and there are no guarantees if it's based on FUSE or such.

Comment: BTW, re-opening your output file over and over by putting the `>> file.txt` on each `echo` line is needlessly inefficient. Better to do it early and reuse that file descriptor -- if you don't need to write to stdout, you can even put a `exec >>file.txt` on your parent script, and any of the `otherscript` instances can just write to stdout and let the redirection do the work.

Comment: @GeorgePBurdell, ...incidentally, the "coalesce your writes" requirement is on of the few reasons why `echo "$(someprogram)" >>outfile.txt` can be useful to use instead of the more efficient `someprogram >>outfile.txt` -- if you don't know how many separate write() calls `someprogram` does, collecting all its output and then writing it yourself all at once reduces the risk that a different program's output will be injected partway through (assuming that the output is short enough to not be split into multiple writes regardless).

Comment: ...if you need to collate larger output, that's a case where GNU parallel -- as much distaste as I may have for that mess of perl -- can come in useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a POSIX-compliant filesystem (ext4, XFS, etc) in `O_APPEND` mode (which is what `>>` gives you), no matter how many processes you have, writes will always go to the bottom; moreover, *if* those writes fit into a single memory page, there's no risk that they'll be split into multiple separately-appended components.

So, this is unsafe:

```
exec >>somefile   # redirects all future stdout to somefile in O_APPEND mode
printf %s 'Hello' # BUGGY: Writing less than a line, so you can get split at this point
echo ' World'
```

...and so is this:

```
exec >somefile     # truncate file and make all future writes go to it, NOT in O_APPEND mode
echo "Hello World" # BUGGY: Not opened with O_APPEND, so our file pointer may not be
                   # ...at the end after other programs have been doing concurrent writes.
```

...but this *is* safe:

```
exec >>somefile     # redirects all future stdout to somefile in O_APPEND mode
echo "Hello World"  # SAFE: Writing a complete line, less than 4kb, in O_APPEND mode.
```

There's a caveat that if your writes are larger than a page (typically 4kb), they may be split into multiple syscalls -- but keep them short, and ensure that each one contains a full record, and you're safe.

Comment: doesn't the output of `echo` getting block-buffered by the libc when stdout isn't a terminal? (I don't know it, maybe not...)

Comment: @hek2mgl, your average C program is subject to that, but `echo` is not.